# ORDER, LIMIT and query with sprintf

Tags: php, mysql

I have problem with include ORDER and LIMIT into SQL query.

```
$STH_1 = $DBH_R->query("SELECT table_name                        
                         FROM information_schema.tables                        
                        WHERE table_name                        
                         LIKE 'v_c_ei\_9%'
                         ");
$stmts_1 = array();

//echo "date = ".       $date."<br>";                                 // $date is today date
$date_60 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-60 day', strtotime($date)));     // $date_60 = today - 60 days


while (($row_1 = $STH_1 -> fetch_assoc()) !== null){

$table_name = $row_1['table_name'];
$stmts_1[] = sprintf("SELECT *  
                        FROM $table_name
                       WHERE (date_time >= '$date_60') AND (ei_code = '1117')     
                     ");     
} 

// at this place I need help, I think. I have few data from every query but I want to reduce the number of solutions to 1 per table

$stmt_1 = implode("\nUNION\n", $stmts_1);  
$stmt_1 .= "\nORDER BY date_time ASC";      
$STH_5_2 = $DBH_R->query($stmt_1);        
while (($row_5_2 = $STH_5_2 -> fetch_assoc()) !== null){
```

the script above is working ok. But I want to limit the number of data (I need only the last one from the every table). I try do it via

```
ORDER BY date_time DESC LIMIT 0,1
```

in the sprintf query but it don't want to work. When I add ORDER ect. I have the answer

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in "while (($row_5_2 ..."

Anyone can help?

Comment: How exactly does your code look when you try it via the sprintf query? Have you checked for errors from mysql?

Comment: @MarkByers probably nothing as it seems like he's using mysqli. Try `echo $DBH_R->error;`

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code it seems likely that you are probably getting the following error (but please check this to be sure):

```
Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY
```

If so, it's because you are missing parentheses. See the manual for [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/union.html):

> To apply ORDER BY or LIMIT to an individual SELECT, place the clause inside the parentheses that enclose the SELECT:
>
> ```
> (SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE a=10 AND B=1 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10)
> UNION
> (SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a=11 AND B=2 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10);
> ```

Comment: This part with UNION and ORDER is working ok. I must select the receiving data BEFORE UNION, and I try to do this as I wrote (with ORDER inside sprintf query) and this ORDER don't want to work ... :(

Comment: the answer is rather simple -> ORDER BY never before UNION always after. Mark - in theory your solution is ok but not in this problem - we don't know how much tables we have - it's imperative from first query ...

Comment: Mark, thnks for your help ... but I remember your comment which one you did delete. Sometimes new doctor be better ...

Comment: @Andrew: "ORDER BY never before UNION always after" That's not a true statement. You can have ORDER BY either before or after UNION. But it means different things depending where you put it. And if you have ORDER BY before UNION, you need parentheses around each select statement `(SELECT ... ORDER BY ...) UNION ...`. And normally you would only do this if you also have a LIMIT in combination with the ORDER BY (which you do).